# Connecting two models that related to the user - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say that:

1. A user has many post
2. A user has many event
3. An event has many post

The question is, how can i connect the related events, post and user?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***`hasManyThrough`*** relationship but that would depend on what you need like for example you want to know the posts of the specific event then you can use the user model as an intermediate model so you can access the posts model. see link below for more info(documentation) about the ***`hasManyThrough`*** relationship.

Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through